# International Url with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, internationalization

I have in my `.htaccess` file this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([\p{L}0-9-]+)$ /cat/article.php?author=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

which matches `http://www.example.com/toto6-titi/tata-tutu2` for example.

Now, I want to have any kind of character in any alphabet, so I change my rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([\p{L}0-9-]+)/([\p{L}0-9-]+)$ /cat/article.php?author=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

`http://www.example.com/toto6-titi/tata-tutu2` and similar kinds of URL are still working but "international" URLs like `http://www.example.com/啊/安` still don't :(

I am on wamp with Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.6.25 and MySQL 5.6.17

My `.htaccess` file is encoded in UTF8

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to escape the `forwawrd slash`? I tested your Regex and it works except for the `/` which had to be escaped by doing `/\ `

Comment: @fanuch Why would you need to escape the (forward) slash? The slash carries no special meaning in mod_rewrite regex, since there are no slash delimiters.

Comment: "any kind of character in any alphabet" - although your regex matches any _letter_ (not _character_). However, `\p{L}` doesn't actually work for me on Apache 2.4 and doesn't even match your first example: `/toto6-titi/tata-tutu2`. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this regex with negated character class:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?author=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```